# Can I use my blender for food processing the ingredients in my Gazpacho?

Tags: blender, gazpacho

My wife and I would like to try Gazpacho, and part of the recipe calls for 'food processing' coarse cuts of red onion, cucumber, tomato and red pepper.

We don't *have* a food processor, and we can't afford one.  What we DO have is a blender.

Can we use or blender to 'food process' these ingredients?

Edit: For those wondering, here's the text directly from the recipe:

> *Put each vegetable separately into a food processor fitted with a steel blade and pulse until it is coarsely chopped.  Do not overprocess!*

Comment: What is the end goal of the processing? What is the desired outcome? If you're reducing it to pulp, that's different than if you're looking for a rough chop.

Comment: @Catija not unclear, imho. Gazpacho is "mush", "pieces" *may* be added after chilling, just before serving. (That's where the knife comes in.)

Comment: @Stephie seeing the other answer and the comment in response to my comment, I think it's definitely unclear to some people.

Comment: A good answer would probably address both possibilities - wanting a complete puree, or wanting some small pieces or texture left.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/34378/67

Comment: A friend of mine makes a salsa in her blender and it is great.   You could cut by hand.

Comment: To answer the question that has popped up - I don't actually know!  The recipe isn't clear if the pieces should be chunky or smooth - and I'm not sure what I'll get if I put the pieces in the blender, vs. if I had a food processor

Comment: If is does not say puree then I but it mean coarse cuts.

Comment: I've tried gazpacho "on location" and it's very smooth, no chunks other than what one adds at the table. At home, I've obtained this using a hand blender and straining the result, which was pretty much what I'd been served in the restaurant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between a food processor and a blender is its shape and how the food is mixed while it is being "cut up".

In a blender, it relies on the funneling action of liquid to mix the food around. Otherwise only the bottom gets blended while the top stays solid.

Food processors usually have a flat bottom and have a mechanism to turn the food as it cuts it up. This results in evenly chopped food.

If you want the gazpacho to end up completely smooth, then the blender will definitely work in this application as it will be liquid enough to get the funnel action going to mix the food around. Keep it mind it would be a good idea to start blending the vegetables with high water content such as tomato and onion first to create a liquid "base" for the other vegetables.

IF you want coarse chunks for the vegetables, it is slightly trickier but still possible to use a blender. You need to work in smaller "batches" and use the pulse functionality instead of just blending. If the batch is too big, you end up with overblended mush on the bottom and unblended chunks on top.

Comment: But if it's soup, mush may be the intent... unfortunately, the question is unclear.

Comment: @Catija well in the question the OP is asking for "corase cuts of red onion, cucumber, tomato and red pepper."

Comment: No, it's saying to process those coarse cuts... but it doesn't say what to process them into.

Comment: The coarse cuts get pureed for gazpacho...

Comment: Really depends on the recipe - [this one](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/gazpacho-recipe.html) says to use a blender in the first place, [this one](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/gazpacho-recipe.html) says to use a food processor "until it is coarsely chopped. Do not overprocess!"

Comment: Hmm looks like I misread the question... regardless I think my answer is still relevant regarding the difference between processing using blender and food processor.

Comment: Regional differences afaik - some are smoother and more liquid, others thicker and often coarser.

Comment: Since the recipe doesn't specify what consistency the pieces should be, this is definitely the answer I'm looking for - we'll probably do it in small batches, because I think we'd prefer the chunks, but a smoother gazpacho I'm sure would also be good.  Thank you!

Comment: I feel the need to add that "If you want the gazpacho to end up completely smooth, then the blender will definitely work" needs a qualifier - the ingredients I listed did *not* include a liquid...and while it seems obvious in hindsight, I didn't realize I needed to add liquid until I took a second jab at it tonight.  So, you might want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @Zibbobz thats not necessarily true. If you blend the tomato and onion first (both very high % water) to create a liquid base, you will not need additional liquid.

Comment: @Jay I found this not to be true - there simply isn't enough liquid made by attempting to blend these ingredients (and it IS an attempt, because they will not blend very well without some liquid).

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can.

For this use case, any tool with a fast-spinning blade that creates a fine puree is suitable, regardles whether it's a food processor, blender or immersion (stick) blender.

Food processors typically offer more functionality, like grating veggies for salads or kneading dough, but that's not required here.

Answer (score 0):

A blender is fine, but please do not let it run continuously. Start-stop-start-stop until the texture for the appropriate item is correct. Place each "corrected" ingredient in a bowl. For avocados, simply mash with a potato masher or fork. Bon appetit!

Comment: I really welcome your enthusiasm but I've seen that most of your answers don't really seem to be based on the content of the question. This question has nothing to do with avocados. Please explain why you think a pulse is preferred over leaving the blender running.

Comment: Pulsing ipso facto chops up items rather than pureeing them. The blender, ironically, mimics the mouth.

Comment: Adding the info as a comment is not useful... please [edit] your answer to add additional information.